# How to observe AtomicInteger variable value change in android?

Tags: android, interface, atomicinteger

I am using AtomicInteger in my android app. Now I want to listen to AtomicInteger variable value changes, how can I listen?

```
private final AtomicInteger hostsCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
     hostsCount.set(10);
     hostsCount.set(101);
```

How can I listen to value changes? How to implement listener for value changes of this AtomicInteger variable?

Comment: wrap it in another class and define a set for it

Answer (score -1):

Have you had a look at RxJava? It has a `Observable<T>` that you can watch for changes. The documentation is here: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html